# python: problem adding data to excel spreadsheets

Tags: python, excel, spreadsheet

I am running 10 simulations from an external program through python. I want to store two sets of data in a single excel file, each set in a spreadsheet. I need that with each iteration in python, new datasets are added below the existing datasets, without replacing the current data. I tried doing this in Python, but it's not working:

```
    # Creates DataFrames for each dataset
    df_mvar = pd.DataFrame([dados_coletados_mvar], columns=nomes_colunas)
    df_tensao = pd.DataFrame([dados_coletados_tensao], columns=nomes_colunas)

    # Excel file name
    nome_excel = 'dados_coletados_juntos.xlsx'

    # Checks if the Excel file already exists
    if os.path.exists(nome_excel):
        # Load existing Excel file into a DataFrame
        try:
            with pd.ExcelWriter(nome_excel, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
                # Adiciona os DataFrames como planilhas diferentes no mesmo arquivo
                df_mvar.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='mvar', index=False)
                df_tensao.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='tensao', index=False)
        except ValueError:
            # If the worksheet already exists, load the file and add the DataFrames to the existing worksheets
            book = load_workbook(nome_excel)
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(nome_excel, engine='openpyxl')
            writer.book = book
            writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

            df_mvar.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='mvar', index=False)
            df_tensao.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='tensao', index=False)

    else:
        # Creates an empty DataFrame if the file does not exist
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        with pd.ExcelWriter(nome_excel, engine='openpyxl', mode='w') as writer:
            # Add DataFrames as different sheets in the same file
            df_mvar.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='mvar', index=False)
            df_tensao.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='tensao', index=False)

    print(f'Data exported to {nome_excel}')
```

I tried putting commands so that if the excel file does not exist, it will be created. This works. Only the data from the first iteration (simulation) is stored in the spreadsheets, from the second iteration onwards, it does not work. The error presented is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Drive\main.py", line 308, in <module>
    df_mvar.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='mvar', index=False)
  File "G:\Drive\main.py\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2345, in to_excel
    formatter.write(
  File "G:\Drive\main.py\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 955, in write
    writer._write_cells(
  File "G:\Drive\main.py\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 463, in _write_cells
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Sheet 'mvar' already exists and if_sheet_exists is set to 'error'.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Drive\main.py", line 314, in <module>
    writer.book = book
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: property 'book' of 'OpenpyxlWriter' object has no setter

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me solve this problem.

Comment: You can't set `writer.book`, it's read-only. Do you even need that line and the `load_workbook` line?

Comment: @Jason I removed these two lines you mentioned and got the following error:: `NameError: name 'book' is not defined. Did you mean: 'bool'?`

Answer (score 0):

The error messages indicates a problem with setting the `book` property of `OpenpyxlWriter`.
This is because `pd.ExcelWriter` does not allow setting the `book` attribute after initialization in this way.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# Create DataFrames
df_mvar = pd.DataFrame([dados_coletados_mvar], columns=nomes_colunas)
df_tensao = pd.DataFrame([dados_coletados_tensao], columns=nomes_colunas)

# Excel file name
nome_excel = 'dados_coletados_juntos.xlsx'

# Function to append data to an existing sheet
def append_df_to_excel(filename, df, sheet_name, startrow=None, **to_excel_kwargs):
    # Startrow is used to determine where to start writing
    startrow = startrow or 0

    # If the file does not exist, create it and write the data
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        df.to_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet_name, **to_excel_kwargs)
    else:
        # Load the existing workbook and sheet
        book = load_workbook(filename)
        with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
            writer.book = book
            writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in book.worksheets}

            # Calculate the index of the last row in the existing sheet
            if startrow == 0 and sheet_name in writer.sheets:
                startrow = writer.sheets[sheet_name].max_row

            # Append the data
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs)

# Append data to the Excel file
append_df_to_excel(nome_excel, df_mvar, sheet_name='mvar', index=False, header=None)
append_df_to_excel(nome_excel, df_tensao, sheet_name='tensao', index=False, header=None)

print(f'Data exported to {nome_excel}')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I modified the code with the changes you suggested but it still doesn't work. The error presented is    `writer.book = book
AttributeError: property 'book' of 'OpenpyxlWriter' object has no setter `